# Swift - fatal error: Array index out of range

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to populate an array with numbers with an increase of 0.1 each like: [0.1,0.2,0.3...]

This code is giving me the error: `fatal error: Array index out of range`
. What am I missing? I thing im declaring something wrong.

I will save it into a structure of type Double.

**My Code**

```
import UIKit

class PrecoDomicilioViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet var euros: UIPickerView!

var pickerData:[Double] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    euros.delegate = self
    euros.dataSource = self




    for var i = 0; i <= 200; i++
    {
        pickerData[i] += 0.1
    }

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    return "\(pickerData[row])"
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    restaurante.portes = pickerData[row]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Finally made it, but there are this strange numbers between 6 and 10.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aELz6.png)
[image]

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: pickerData[i] += 0.1

Comment: You really need a separate question. Hint: floating point numbers can not represent most decimal numbers (non whole numbers) exactly, that is what you ar seeing here. It is a problem when changing bases, here from base 10 to base 2 which `Double` uses. For exact decimal numbers such as for money and calculators use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add items to a Swift array with the subscript operator, you need to use append.

> NOTE
>   You can’t use subscript syntax to append a new item to the end of an array.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l

Use `append()`, examples:

```
shoppingList.append("Flour")
pickerData.append(0.1)
```

Comment: How do I populate with append?

Comment: Solved my question. In other languages we simply use +=. Thank you.

Comment: In Swift += is used for append an array, ex: `shoppingList += ["Baking Powder", "Tomatoes"]`